# react-native-firebase - App Crash after Push Notification Received (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a **NodeJS Server** and when my **React Native app** receive a Push Notification from the Server, the app stop working.

> In the **Emulator** the app just close and in the Cellphone with a Release APK isntalled the app close and show an alert saying that the application stop working.

Here I can show some configuration I added in my Android Application

**android/build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
```

**Notifications Listeners**

```
export const configureMessaging = async () => {
  try {
    const enabled = await FirebaseMessaging.hasPermission();
    log('Push Notifications enabled?', enabled);
    return enabled;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}; // This is returning true

export const configureOnNotificationDisplayed = () => FirebaseNotifications.onNotificationDisplayed((notification) => {
  // Process your notification as required
  // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID.
  // You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
  console.log(notification);
});

export const configureOnNotification = () => FirebaseNotifications.onNotification((notification) => {
  // Process your notification as required
  console.log(notification);
});

export const configureOnNotificationOpened = () => FirebaseNotifications.onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
  // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
  // Get information about the notification that was opened
  console.log(notification);
});
```

I attached a debugger in the AVM and no error was throw

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624', transport:
>   'socket'
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624',
>   transport: 'socket'

**Note**

> I do not know what happened in iOS because the app is not configured
>   to use iOS

Comment: Check the Android Studio log to see if you can find why the app crashed.  I'm guessing you need to enable permissions

Comment: Add something useful, the configuration you gave is just generic to others

Comment: @AngusTay I'm listening the Notifications in my Loader component

Comment: @MikeM Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624', transport: 'socket'
was throw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I had another dependency that was using the Push Notifications. I removed it and everything works perfect

Comment: what was the other dependency ?